# JavaScript - Least finite number

Tags: javascript

What is the least finite number (i.e., the negative number furthest away from zero) in JavaScript? Is it `-Number.MAX_VALUE`?

I'm only concerned with primitive numbers, not `BigInt`s.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, `-Number.MAX_VALUE` seems right. (Just asking out of curiosity, or…?)

Comment: Fair, but you still have `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP wants.  Does he mean negative number closest to zero, or negative number farthest away from zero?

Comment: the smallest negative number would be `-Number.MIN_VALUE` since that the number closest to zero without being zero ... just like the smallest positive number is Number.MIN_VALUE - I think the question needs clarification

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, and thank you to all who brought it up. I meant the negative number furthest away from zero.

I changed "smallest" to "least," hoping that would be more clear. If anyone thinks of a better way to clarify my intent, I would greatly appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINITE NUMBER, in that case it is (Number.MAX_VALUE * -1)
Number type is a signed integer.

which is
-1.7976931348623157e+308

Comment: that's not correct.  it's 5 * (10  ^ -324).  E-notation is based off of just moving the decimal point.  This number is still positive, so the answer is wrong anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest **finite number** is `-Number.MAX_VALUE` = **-1.7976931348623157e+308**

The smallest **infinite number** is `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/NEGATIVE_INFINITY

Comment: Is it a finite number?

Comment: The name says it: `infinite`.

Comment: So when the question asks for the smallest finite number…?

Comment: Ok, I didn't see this fineness.